# How to validate my email field with help of selenium-webdriver

Tags: selenium-webdriver, email-verification

```
<div class="form_content clearfix">
<p>Please enter your email address to create an account.</p>
<div class="alert alert-danger" id="create_account_error" style="display:none">
</div>
<div class="form-group form-ok">
<label for="email_create">Email address</label>
<input type="text" class="is_required validate account_input form-control" data-validate="isEmail" id="email_create" name="email_create" value="">
</div>



                    <div class="submit">
                        <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="back" value="my-account">                     
<button class="btn btn-default button button-medium exclusive" type="submit" id="SubmitCreate" name="SubmitCreate">
                            <span>
                                <i class="icon-user left"></i>
                                Create an account
                            </span>
                        </button>
                        <input type="hidden" class="hidden" name="SubmitCreate" value="Create an account">
                    </div>
                </div>
```

I am trying to validate my mail id using selenium web driver. I am entering mail id in mail id field and then its validate that the mail id format is correct or not a existing mail id.Please view the attached image.

Answer (score 0):

> I am trying to validate my mail id using selenium web driver. I am
>   entering mail id in mail id field and then its validate that the mail
>   id format is correct or not a existing mail id.Please view the
>   attached image

[Please click here to view this image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B1wun.png)